# Inherit List of Self, recursive definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, python-typing

I would like to build a recursive-type class, where the class is a list of things including itself. How can this be achieved? It doesn't seem to work even with `from __future__ import annotations`.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Union, List

class A:
    pass

class AList(List[Union[A, AList]]):
    pass
```

The intent is the take advantage of various builtin methods of `list`, e.g. `append`, `extend`, `__iter__`, etc., while also be able to add custom methods.

It's possible to simply subclass `list`. Is it adding anything to specify the types elements I will have in AList via `List[Union[A, AList]]`?

Comment: You don't actually have any annotations there for the future import to turn into strings.

Comment: You have to distinguish between types and type hints. `AList = List[Union[A, Alist]]` is what you would want, if any type checkers actually supported recursively defined hints. (Although `mypy` might have partial support now.)

Comment: @chepner, can you explain a bit how to distinguish types and type hints? Suppose I want to add some custom method to AList that's not in list, can I still achieve that with what you suggested? Thanks!

Comment: `A` is a type. `List[Union[A, Alist]]` is a hint you can use to annotate a name to suggest the type of values it should accept, not something you should inherit from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following syntax:

```
class AList(List[Union[A, AList]]):
```

I don't think it's what you're trying to do. It basically says that the class `AList` is a subclass of `list`.

I think something like this is what you want. This should work for Python 3.7+ with the included `__future__` import, though I'm not sure how `mypy` would handle it (it seems fine on Pycharm at least)

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass


class A:
    ...


@dataclass
class AList:

    data: list[A | AList]

    @staticmethod
    def my_custom_method():
        print('Hello world!')


# creating instance of A
a = A()

# does not type check
my_list = AList(a)
my_list = AList([1, 2])

# type checks
my_list1 = AList([a])
my_list2 = AList([my_list1])

# True
assert my_list1.data[0] == a
assert my_list2.data[0] == my_list1

print(my_list1)
print(my_list2)

my_list2.my_custom_method()
# Hello world!
```

#### Subclassing from list

Note that you can still access the list object from the above example via the `data` attribute, which should support list operations like `append` and `extend` for example.

If you *do* intend to subclass from `list`, the following approach should work and also work well in Pycharm for example.

Note that I remove the `__future__` import here, since it's not needed actually; as the annotation `A | AList` is already forward declared in this case, as a string.

```py
from typing import List


class A:
    ...


class AList(List['A | AList']):

    def first_element(self):
        return self[0]


# creating instance of A
a = A()

# does not type check
my_list = AList(["testing"])
my_list = AList([1, 2])

# type checks
my_list1 = AList([a])
my_list2 = AList([my_list1])

# True
assert my_list1[0] == a
assert my_list2[0] == my_list1

print(my_list1)
print(my_list2)

elem = my_list2.first_element()
print(elem)
# [<__main__.A object at 0x103809750>]
# True
assert isinstance(elem, AList)
```

Comment: @rv.kvtch thanks, this is a good alternative. Though, I did intend to make it a subclass of list to take advantage of various methods from list e.g. `append`, `extend`, and `__iter__`. (Updated question.) Any way to modify your answer to have it also inherit from list?

Comment: Hmm... would it not be possible to access the `data` attribute instead, which is a list? For example, `alist.append(A())`. If not, I can update the answer if subclassing is indeed what you want.

Comment: I would prefer subclassing if possible for more elegant code :) but if that's too cumbersome, this also works. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim no problem, I updated my answer with an approach with subclassing from list, if that's what you're wanting to do instead.